# How to display custom table without using views?

Tags: theming

I have tried it to display the table by using core PHP concept and it display the table but at the top of the page now i need to display inside my page my current display is below

[image]

and my code for view is

```
function testing_db_viewall($form, &$form_state){
    $result = db_select('infobox_new')
    ->fields('infobox_new', array('name','emailid','contactno','nid'))        
    ->execute();

    $entries = $result;
    $output ='';
    $rows = array();

    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    // print_r($entry);
    // echo "<br>";
        $rows[] = array( $entry->name, $entry->emailid, $entry->contactno, l('edit','examples/edit/'.$entry->nid), );
    }
  // Make a table for them.
    $header = array(t('Name'),t('Email id'), t('Contact No'),t('edit'));
    $output .= theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

     echo $output;
}
```

I want to display my table after my title i.e. "Custom Table View"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My issue has been resolved

I made silly mistake in my menu creation link.

[image]

Comment: Please add some details about what that "silly mistake" was. The way your answer now looks it doesn't help anybody to learn from it ... It may help to get your downvote (not from me) remove ...

Answer (score 2):

Instated of "echo"

> echo $output;

You have to write

> return $output;

Comment: Hi Smalution,

i have tried with your suggestion but i got error

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in 

C:\xampp\htdocs\pracs\staff\includes\form.inc on line 1079

Comment: why you creating form type instated of creating simple function testing_db_viewall(){ }

Comment: Can you elaborate

Comment: ok remove function arguments ($form, &$form_state). let me know if its not clear to you

Comment: no change same output

Comment: HI, Simalution, my issue has been resolved actually one silly mistake is done by me on menu creation and because of that table was coming at the top.
Thanks you so much for your help and valuable time.

Comment: Nice to hear your issue has been solved. Go ahead :)

Comment: Hi HUNK, If you got your answer you can write your answer and accept that. So that question will remove from unanswered questions queue. Else if my answer is helpful for you can accept that also.

Comment: Your always welcome

Comment: @Smalution I think you mean "instead", not "instated" ... typo?